# Cómo corregir este Trigger y trigger function en PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

tengo una función en postgres para cuando se realiza cualquier accion(Insertar,Eliminar,Actualizar) me capture los datos que se cambiaron o insertaron, pero no me esta funcionando, en SQL lo hacia mediante la tabla `INSERTED`, o `DELETED` para las eliminaciones, mi pregunta es, ¿Hay alguna función o tabla en postgres que sea como la tabla `INSERTED/DELETED` de SQL?

Adjunto mi disparador

```
-- Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER logcategories
DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON public.categoriestemp
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.logcategories();


--funcion
CREATE FUNCTION public.logcategories()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

 IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
  INSERT INTO log_categories
   SELECT nextval('log_categories_idlog_seq'), 'I', now(), inet_client_addr(), current_user  ,NEW;
  RETURN NEW;

 ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
  INSERT INTO log_categories
   SELECT nextval('log_categories_idlog_seq'), 'U', now(), inet_client_addr(), current_user ,NEW;
  RETURN NEW;

 ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
  INSERT INTO log_categories
   SELECT nextval('log_categories_idlog_seq'), 'D', now(), inet_client_addr(), current_user ,OLD;
  RETURN OLD;
 END IF;

 RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.logcategories()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Es decir, tienes un trigger y una trigger function. Entonces, ¿qué quieres decir con No me funciona? Podrías ser más específico, por favor? Este código se ejecuta correctamente? (no lo creo) Por qué el trigger no tiene BEFORE \ AFTER update or delete? Los triggers tienen un momento de dispararse y no lo estás definiendo correctamente. No existen esas tablas que mencionas, existe (como en casi todas las BD) un registro NEW y un registro OLD (que puede o no estar vacío dependiendo de la operación y el tiempo de disparo del trigger)

Comment: En Postgres, si defines el trigger por fila `FOR EACH ROW` se ejecutará una vez por cada fila alterada, si lo que quieres es "capturar" todas las filas que una consulta altera, por ejemplo `DELETE FROM table WHERE id < 100` debes definir el nivel del trigger como `STATEMENT`, es decir `FOR EACH STATEMENT`, en este trigger puedes definir un alias para las pseudotablas creadas `REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS inserted`

Comment: No, depronto me hice entender mal, el trigger se dispara en el momento que debe, pero quiero saber si la forma en la que estoy capturando los datos es la correcta, es asi como debe ser? o como lo explico, hay alguna tabla como la de SQL donde se almacenen los datos modificados?

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes intentar asi

```
CREATE TRIGGER logcategories BEFORE
DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON public.categoriestemp
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.logcategories();


--funcion
CREATE FUNCTION public.logcategories()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

 IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
  INSERT INTO log_categories
   SELECT nextval('log_categories_idlog_seq'), 'I', now(), inet_client_addr(), current_user  ,NEW.*;
  RETURN NEW;

 ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
  INSERT INTO log_categories
   SELECT nextval('log_categories_idlog_seq'), 'U', now(), inet_client_addr(), current_user ,NEW.*;
  RETURN NEW;

 ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
  INSERT INTO log_categories
   SELECT nextval('log_categories_idlog_seq'), 'D', now(), inet_client_addr(), current_user ,OLD.*;
  RETURN OLD;
 END IF;

 RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.logcategories()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```